# How to Choose Basis Solutions for Eigenvalue Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

I have a real, fourth order linear operator $L$ and want to solve the eigenvalue problem
\begin{equation*}
Lv = \lambda v,
\end{equation*}
where $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$.  I further want to impose periodic boundary conditions, but I will mention that later.  I know that I will find roots $r_j$ of the characteristic polynomial of $L - \lambda$, these roots $r_j$ will give me exponential functions as solutions so that the general solution is
\begin{equation*}
v(x) = \sum_{j=1}^4 c_j e^{r_j x}.
\end{equation*}
Now, I want to impose periodic boundary conditions 
\begin{equation*}
v^{(k)}(0) = v^{(k)}(L), \ 0 \leq k \leq 3.
\end{equation*}
for some $L > 0$, in order to determine which values of $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ give nontrivial $v$.

The whole point of my question is this: is $\{ e^{r_jx} \}_{j=1}^4$ a suitable basis for finding the $\lambda$ that work, or should I convert to real and complex parts (as one does when $\lambda$ is real meaning the the roots $r_j$ come in complex pairs) in order to find a basis?  This is also confusing to me because in the latter case, I will have between four and eight basis functions depending on roots being real or complex.

Comment: There is no need to take real and imaginary parts.  It only makes things more complicated.

Comment: But I should at least write the complex exponentials out as $e^{a_jx}( \cos (b_jx) + i \sin (b_jx))$ in order to find suitable $\lambda$, yes?